# Find error in Multithreaded Code

Tags: java, multithreading

I have faced this question in an interview,where interviewer has asked me to find the bug in this code.

```
public class Thread1 {


        private static  boolean interruptedTask=false;

        private static class MyClass extends Thread{

            public void run(){

                while(!interruptedTask){

                //Do some time consuming task for more than 5 secs

                }

            }

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread task=new MyClass();
            task.start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            interruptedTask=true;
            try {
                task.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
```

The only wrong part i am guessing is interruptedTask variable should be volatile,since it is used in multiple threads.

Please suggest.

Comment: You should try to be more specific in your questions. What have you tried and what is not behaving properly?

Comment: @David This seems to be pure example code which does not belong on Code Review. Please read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: @David - given the title of the question I believe the code does not work, which makes it very off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @rolfl: Potentially, which is why it was a suggestion and not a close vote.  Though in that case the OP would do well to actually describe the problem...

Comment: This question was recently asked in interview.I was not able to predict the mistake,thats why i m posting.

Comment: well as you noticed the flag interruptedTask has to be final in order to pass it to a thread or volatile , the code snippet you shared its bit wrong cause of the statics  and as you pass the variable in the thread , it will never be interrupted in order to change the flag to true. try making the variable synchronized

Comment: @AntJavaDev `static` is not a problem here:  There's two threads, both running in `static` methods of the same class, communicating through a `static` variable of the same class.  Also, you should explain what you mean by "making the variable synchronized".  You can't just add the `synchronized` keyword to the declaration of a variable.

Comment: ye sorry , tried to mean volatile , or better make the method that should access a field like that , synchronized , as for statics , i am not so sure you want them in a concurrent environment , except the public final static fields , which also might create leaks , cause of thread's local memory , also the code snippet in the question plays perfect with statics and all

Answer (score 3):

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        interruptedTask=true;
```

What I am seeing here is that you will always set interruptedTask to true, even if you just wait for 5000ms. You should consider putting the final line within your catch block to get what I am assuming is the expected behavior.

Comment: I am not sure the actual purpose of the code, but when you reach the try block you will always fall through to set interrupted to true. I assume that you only want to set interrupted to true when you catch the exception within the catch block. That being said, I do not have extensive java multithreading experience so there may be more.

Comment: _I am not sure the actual purpose of the code._  Exactly!  The OP has given you the same information that was given in the interview.  The interviewer wanted the OP to spot an anti-pattern in this code that is virtually always wrong no matter _what_ the purpose of the code.  Failure to synchronize the communication through the `interruptedTask` variable is the only such anti-pattern that I can see.  Hint:  Think about what the example would look like if you changed the name `interruptedTask` to `timeToStop` or `shutdownRequested` or some such.

Comment: If you look at the edit history you will see that the interview comment was not included when I began this discussion.